# How to make WMP to locate my custom codec?

Tags: windows-media-player

Hieverybody,
I'm writing a custom codec for my encrypted mp3 file.(I know it sounds weird)
The problem is making WMP locate and install my custom codec when it sees my encrypted file.
There was WMPlugins.com once, but it is retired now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, only a select few were allowed to be downloaded on request.
The reason for that is that Microsoft can't be responsible for every code it is requested to host and the inspection process is to hard (both legal and melware wise).
The only thing you can do is to preinstall the codec.